# Using 'If' functions in a 'For' loop over Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this Pandas DataFrame.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su3Ck.png)

I am trying to figure out how to write this in python.

For each row I want to say, "if  the 'Bid_Size' is a different value that the 'Bid_Size' in the previous row, highlight this cell.

For instance in my provided data set, row #3/column-'Bid_Size' would be highlighted because it is a different value than the 'Bid_Size' in the previous row.

I am guessing it would go something like

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('DataBase.csv', header=None, names=['Book_ID','Asset','Best_Bid','Bid_Size','Best_Ask', 'Ask_Size'])  

df = pd.DataFrame(file)

def highlight_yellow(df):
    for rows in df:
        if df['Best_Bid'] != -['Best_Bid']:
            return['highlight:yellow']

df.style.apply(highlight_yellow)
```

Thank you, I just can not figure this one out.

Comment: don't post your dataframe as an image. post it as text. do you expect us to transcribe it from the image?

Answer (score 2):

You could shift Best_Bid down one and then compare to assign a value. First create a highlight column with your default value, then reassign.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"Best_Bid":[1,1,1,2,2,5,1,5,4,4,4]})
>>> df["Highlight"] = ""
>>> df["Highlight"][df["Best_Bid"] != df["Best_Bid"].shift(1)] = "highlight:yellow"
>>> df
    Best_Bid         Highlight
0          1  highlight:yellow
1          1                  
2          1                  
3          2  highlight:yellow
4          2                  
5          5  highlight:yellow
6          1  highlight:yellow
7          5  highlight:yellow
8          4  highlight:yellow
9          4                  
10         4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am trying to figure out now how to apply this to highlight cells within my 'Best_Bid column. This gave me some good framework to use!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of data you have, but I will make an example. Suppose that you have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Best_Bid' : ['value_a', 'value_b', 'value_a','value_a']
})
```

Now create a function to paint your rows:

```
 def highlight(column_value, value_to_compare):
    color_a = 'background-color: yellow'
    color_b = 'background-color: red'
    return color_a if column_value==value_to_compare else color_b
```

Now, apply this function:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: highlight(x, "value_a"))
```

And you will get:

[image]

**This function will allow you to handle your color and indexes in an independent way!**

Comment: couple of things: I think the columns should display their original values. also, `numpy.where` would be useful in consolidating your two assignments

Comment: yes, I had an error in my solution, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I am having trouble as to how to apply your function to my dataset, but you have given me some starting ground!

Comment: Great to know that. If you find useful my answer, please vote for it.